# openfoam ./makeParaview

Tags: paraview, openfoam

i am currently building openfoam 1912 from source and have some trouble building paraview. I just build Qt and Cmake but as soon as i type `./makeParaview qt-5.9.9 5.6.3`i get the following error:

```
./makeParaView: 64: local: -DWM_DP: bad variable name

./makeParaView: 64: ./makeParaView: -DOPENFOAM: bad variable name
```

A similar error occurs when i try to make VTK / Adios2. Any idea where i took the wrong turn?

Greetings

Gabbagandalf

Comment: Are you following the installation guide verbatim? Dependent ParaView installation is always pain in the neck. Have you downloaded ParaView into the ThirdParty directory?

Comment: as mentioned i built Qt and Cmake, in the build.md those are the only necessary mentioned. There is already a ParaView inside of the ThirdParty dir. I am not that good with linux system, do you know what there errors exactly mean?

Comment: The issue has been reported in the GitLab issue tracker: https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/issues/1541

Answer (score 0):

As discussed and resolved in these GitLab [ticket-1](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/issues/1541) and [ticket-2](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/ThirdParty-common/issues/48):
The issue seems to be `Ubuntu` related.

**Solution:**

Prior to execute `./makeParaview`, switch to `bash`:

1. Change the first line of `makeParaView` script to `#!/bin/bash`
2. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash`
3. `./makeParaView`

Answer (score 0):

The *proper* solution is related to [shell quoting issues](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/ThirdParty-common/issues/48)

```
- flag="$(stripCompilerFlags $flag)" 
+ flag="$(stripCompilerFlags "$flag")"
```

but in the meantime you can simply change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` - it is more forgiving.